# Using height as percentage in html5

Tags: html, image

(I am new to html5, and don't know anything about css.)

When adding an image, if i assign width a percentage, it works fine i.e. the image width will be that percentage of the browser window width.

However, assigning height a percentage does not work at all. I can give whatever percentage i want and it will still render the orginal size or according to width (if specified). So, if i type :

```
<img  width="40%" height="60%" src="saitama wall.jpg" >
```

it would just take width into consideration and adjust height according to original picture instead of taking 60% of window height.

**Why does this happen?**Is it because webpages have bounds only on width not the height (as you can scroll down)?

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/setting-height-width-images-important-again/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a page can scroll, so setting % of height is not the way to do this,
if you are looking to set an image compared to the browser window size, try using vw (view width) and vh (view height) instead of percentage ie

```
<img src="saitama wall.jpg" style="width:40vw; height:60vh">
```

more info about css units:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

Handling image dimensions is not recommended using HTML attributes. Using CSS is a better option. So using CSS your IMG tag should be as follows

```
<img  style="width:40vw; height:60vh" src="saitama wall.jpg" >
```